# Как сохранять состояния RecyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview, pagination

как во время подгрузки следующей порции ячеек, сохранять состояние списка?
Я использую mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mRecyclerAdapter.getLastPos()), и если я в момент подгрузки новых ячеек остаюсь в самом низу списка то все ок, но если я в момент подгрузки скролю список который уже есть в верх, то в момент отрисовки меня кидает в самый конец списка(т.е. если у меня было 10 ячеек я вызвал подзрузку следующих 10, и проскролил до 5-ой, то в момент отрисовки следующих 10-ти меня кидает на 10-ю).
Если не использовать scrollToPosition, то в момент отрисовки след. ячеек кидает в самый верх списка.

Comment: а как вы вставляете в список после подрузки? notifyDatasetChanged()?

Comment: да, именно им самым.

Comment: дополните кодом